# double colon in host identifier when connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 nodejs application on Linux CentOs7 server. The first is running on the main domain and the second on a subdomain.  Both have to connect to the same MongoDb replicaset but on different databases. They have different username and password in the connection string.
The application on the main domain is connecting without problems, but the subdomain gets the error: double colon in host identifier.

This is the config file for the MongoDb on the subdomain:

```
module.exports = {
'secret': 'mysecret',
'database': 'mongodb://myUID:myPass@127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27018,127.0.0.1:27019/mySubDomainApp,replset: { rs_name: "rs0" }',
'hashidsecret': 'theSecret',
'cryptrsecret': 'thecryptosecret' 
};
```

Comment: Can you add stacktrace of it , that make it clear to understand more .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the config file:

```
module.exports = {
    'secret': 'jK5skCC5spUWqrs7p',
    'database': 'mongodb://fIujhYes:24KWWisPjfB52@127.0.0.1:27017/challenger?replicaSet=rs0',
    'hashidsecret': 'MCZ4584jHMQsfC',
    'cryptrsecret': 'wYrdS8KV51Rsvd',
    'presetRoles': ['systemadmin', 'admin']
};
```

Changing `,replset: { rs_name: "rs0" }` to `?replicaSet=rs0` did the trick.
But very strange that the first config file works on the main domain on the same server.